# Environment inside \newcommand

Tags: macros, environments

This is my first question so feel free to correct it in any way.

I am struggling with the following problem: using an `environment in a \newcommand`.

I want to define the command `\describe` this way:
*(It takes a bash command name (#1), an example using it (#2) and a description (#3)).*

```
\newcommand{\describe}[3]{
\subsection*{#1}
\begin{lstlisting}
#2
\end{lstlisting}
{\colorbox{gray}{#1}\ #3}
}
```

The only thing I am getting is a

```
"no legal \end found"
```

error.

So my question is: Is there any way to use an environment inside a new command?

Comment: `\lstinline` is what you want.

Comment: In addition to Manuels correct answer, in latex there are certain constructions that cannot be used inside a macro definition. Verbatim like constructions like listings are among these.

Comment: @Manuel this command stops after the end of the code snippet. I want the look of the environment (takes a full line)

Comment: @daleif how to work around this problem?

Comment: There is no work around, if you want the look of the environment, use the env directly, it will also give your code a much better structure.

Comment: @daleif actually I am building a bigger command taking 3 variables and building them together, where the code snippet is positioned in the middle between a subsection and a simple text.
Using the environment would force me to brake up the whole construction...

Comment: Well, perhaps you should show us what you're trying in a document, not just a fragment. We might give you some guidance

Comment: verbatim commands like `\verb` `verbatim` and `listings` can not be used inside the argument of another command.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I added the full construction, perhaps it's clearer this way. Thanks for all the comments so far!

Comment: @4ster: I've got another idea, since you're using a colorbox as well

Answer (score 1):

A `\newcommand` with a verbatim content environment does not work together (without much ado) and my approach will not work always.

Verbatim environment such as `lstlisting` need a definite end point where the verbatim content stops and the usual `LaTeX` (i.e. the expansion) should continue. this can be done with `\scantokens{...}` to provide the `\end{tcblisting}` here as the end token.

I've decided to use `tcolorbox` and its listings options, since a colorbox is apparently involved.

There are many configuration options of `tcolorbox`, I've restricted to the main feature here (also the usage of specialized listings environments in conjunction with `xparse`).

The `xparse` package allows to provide verbatim arguments `v` which are just taken as status quo.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}





\NewDocumentCommand{\describe}{O{}+m+v+m}{%
  \scantokens{%
    \begin{tcblisting}{enhanced,
        before={\subsection*{#2}},
        title={#4},
        listing only,
        colback={white!80!black},
        sharp corners,
        colbacktitle={white!60!black},
        boxrule=1pt,
        left=5pt,
        #1}
      #3
    \end{tcblisting}
  }%
}


\describe{My command}{ls -ltr}{Foo}

\describe[colback=green!40!white]{Another command}{pdflatex thisniceexample}{Do you like what you see?}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: so there's basically no workaround that doesn't involve the usage of `xparse`?
I'm just a bit confused that there's no simple LaTeX solution to such a simple problem - the question that has been marked as a duplicate by @egreg doesn't help neither...

Comment: @4ster: Perhaps you can  omit the `v` argument and `xparse`, but not `\scantokens`. And it's not a simple problem, but you have to prevent LaTe interpreting your bash code as  LaTeX