# How to include a highlighted source code from external tex file?

Tags: beamer, listings, input, highlighting, code

I have tried to minimise my scenario here. Basically, I would like to call each piece of highlighted code from external tex file over the beamer class.

There are two .tex files

- code.tex
- main.tex

My aim is to store codes inside code.tex and call them inside main.tex based on the title in order to tidy up everything. If I call \testCode{} on the main.tex, there are various issues. Any idea how I can handle this process ?

code.tex

```
\def\testCode{
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=CStyle]
        #include <stdio.h>
        int main(void)
        {
           printf("Hello World!"); 
        }
    \end{lstlisting}
}

\def\testText{
    Test input text
}
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Madrid}         % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{beaver}    % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{serif}      % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{mGreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mGray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mPurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backgroundColour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{CStyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backgroundColour},   
    commentstyle=\color{mGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{mGray},
    stringstyle=\color{mPurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    language=C
}

\input{code.tex}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title here}
    \testText{}
    \testCode{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this can be a solution for you, I would rather have my codes in their dedicated files (e.g., code.c) and then use this command:

```
\lstinputlisting[style=CStyle]{code.c}
```

Otherwise, there is an answer here: [Environment inside \newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302099/environment-inside-newcommand)

### Edit

You can also include several codes from the same file at different places of your document by using the optional arguments `firstline` and `lastline` of the `\lstinputlisting` commands. You can also apply different styles, so that you could mix different languages in the same source file, whatever the reason you want to do this.

I show you the result first. Then follow the codes.

[image: How it renders]

Main code from the question, extended with the proposed answer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Madrid}         % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
    \usecolortheme{beaver}    % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
    \usefonttheme{serif}      % or try serif, structurebold, ...
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{mGreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mGray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mPurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backgroundColour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{CStyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backgroundColour},   
    commentstyle=\color{mGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{mGray},
    stringstyle=\color{mPurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    language=C
}
\lstdefinestyle{LatexStyle}{
    language=[LaTeX]TeX
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{title here}
        A C code:
        \lstinputlisting[style=CStyle,firstline=2,lastline=7]{code.tex}

        A \LaTeX\ code from same file:
        \lstinputlisting[style=LatexStyle,firstline=10,lastline=10]{code.tex}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Source file containing different pieces of codes to include in the document:

```
% First code: C
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World!"); 
}

% Second code: LaTeX
\newcommand{\testText}{Test input text}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: The point is here calling each piece of code section from the same source file based on the LaTeX definition name. The answer you gave is not what I am asking. The answer you point assumes that each piece of code is saved in different file. Although I have tried your suggestions, it could not them if each piece of code are stored in the same file whether it is .c or .tex.

Comment: @ozturkib is it better now that I have edited my answer?

Comment: Thanks for the update!